# What really happens On the BRAS or Border Network Gateway Computer At Isp

Tags: routing, internet

first question is what type of operating system is used by BRAS Or Border Network Gateway computer.I sit Linux Or Windows Server or it can be any. I have read about windows server Gateway that is support BGP protocol.do most isp use Linux or windows and which one will be better. Second question is Is the Billing software installed at the BRAS Computer or im lost. just asking out of curiosity

Comment: Sadly, questions about networks you don't control are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends of the type of vendor for the BRAS.However,BRAS doesn't use Consumer grade Linux or Windows User,simply because their architecture is not designed for a highly critical device in an ISP infrastructure.

Most of the BRAS equipment vendors will have their own proprietor OS with different licenses for their expensive features and cards. Huawei ME60-X16 uses proprietary OS and will support the below mentioned use cases.

Switching Capacity :25.2 Tbit/s

User access protocol: PPPoE, PPPoEoA, IPoE, IPoEoA, and PPPoA 802.1X
User authentication protocol: PAP, CHAP, MSCHAP, RADIUS, and HWTACACS
User accounting protocol: RADIUS, HWTACACS, and COPS
User authorization protocol: RADIUS, HWTACACS, and COPS
Policy protocol: COPS and COA

22 slots, including 2 MPUs (1:1 backup), 4 SFUs (3+1 backup), and 16 LPUs

Similarly a BRAS provided by Juniper or ZTE will have different spec and their own OS.